# AutoSave information every 5 minutes- How to implement?

Tags: visualforce, controller, time

How would I go about triggering a apex controller method every certain period of time?

This is the general idea I need to implement: "Autosave information every 5 minutes on a visual force page". I already have a save function written in my apex controller, which I used for save buttons.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `<apex:actionPoller/>` to implement your requirement

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="autoSaveController"> 
<apex:form id="form1">
<apex:actionPoller action="{!save}" rerender="form1" interval="300"/>
<apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

In the `save()` method in the controller class you can hold page values in the List, Map or any other suitable ways and finally call commit if necessary.